# Synchronize PC to Internet Time for Twitter in Android?

Tags: android, twitter, synchronization

Why does Twitter need to have my computer synchronized with the Internet Time? I'm trying to implement log in and tweet on Android and I get this strange warning about synchronization. My PC is part of a domain, so I can't change its time. 
Why does it do that and what other options do i have?

PS: I use Twitter4j lybrary :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the exact error message, I would guess that the certificates that Twitter uses for authentication have a specific start and end date.  If your computer is showing the date as 01/01/1970 and Twitter's cert starts at 09/10/2011 - you'll get errors.

Just speculation - post the full error so we can see what's going on.